# How to create a class in a dbml file dynamically

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I'm using linq to sql and I need to have a class in the dbml file where some of its properties are created dynamically. Is there a way to have a class in a dbml file with some predefined properties and some dynamic properties?

Or is there any way to create a class in a dbml file dynamically?

Comment: I'd doubt it. The most dynamic way I am aware of is to drag and drop your tables in the .dbml

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely! Every class generated by LINQ to SQL is marked `partial`. That means you can add to the class in a separate file, as long as you name it correctly.

Generated File:

```
namespace MyApp 
{
    public partial class MyDataContext : System.Data.Linq.DataContext
    {
       // Generated Code
    }
}
```

Your file

```
namespace MyApp 
{
    public partial class MyDataContext
    {
       public string MyProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This works with the DataContext class, Table classes, and Stored Procedure response classes, etc.